# Decorative Icon Fonts Accessibility

Tags: accessibility, icon-fonts

For decorative icon fonts and other applicable components, is there a difference between using aria-hidden="true" and using role="img" alt=""

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference, but not a massive one.

`aria-hidden="true"` will completely remove it from the accessibility tree.

`role="img" alt=""` will still add it to the accessibility tree as a decorative image. (well an  image with no `alt` description if we are being technical - it won't get read out and that is what we care about)

Now this doesn't cause issues for majority of screen reader users. But some screen reader users may use a screen reader with very high verbosity settings (how much detail gets read out).

In this case it can actually be possible that with `role="img"` that the image is read out as "image, no description".

It is an edge case, but one to consider.

As an additional thought - [support for `role="img"` may not be so great](https://scottaohara.github.io/tests/aria-img/) (there isn't a lot of data on this)

I would encourage the use of `aria-hidden="true"` and *perhaps* add `role="presentation"` as support is good for that as a nice fall-back.